How to fully disconnect and reconnect a USB keyboard from PC on Windows?
I have my USB keyboard (ASUS ROG Strix Scope RX) that has LED lights, connected to my laptop.
I need its LEDs to turn off when turning off my external monitor (the only one I use actually, since the lid of my laptop is closed), so I use OpenRGB to do this. The LED light goes off as expected, but then it seems that OpenRGB has full and exclusive control over the LEDs, I can't control them with Fn + arrow keys anymore. The only solution is manually unplug and then replug the keyboard.
Main Question: How can I automatically fully disconnect and then reconnect my keyboard, as if pulling its USB cable out of my laptop and then back in, using scripts or commands?
I've tried using USBDeview.exe or devcon.exe but no results.
Below there's a script I've tried creating to use devcon.exe to remove and then rescan for devices, but it doesn't work well, actually the classic Windows sound of USB device connected is played, but it doesn't appear to go far enough and isn't like actually disconnecting and reconnecting the device.

script.bat
@echo off


:: Stop HID service before disconnection
powershell -Command "Stop-Service -Name 'hidserv'"

:: Remove the keyboard device (HID device)
devcon remove "HID\VID_0B05&PID_1951&MI_02&COL04"
timeout 2

:: Disable the USB Root Hub 3.0 to disconnect all devices connected to it
devcon disable "USB\ROOT_HUB30"
timeout 2

:: Enable the USB Root Hub 3.0 to reconnect the devices
devcon enable "USB\ROOT_HUB30"
timeout 2

:: Rescan devices to ensure proper device detection
devcon rescan
timeout 2

:: Restart the HID service to reset the keyboard driver
powershell -Command "Start-Service -Name 'hidserv'"

:: Rescan again for any devices
devcon rescan


Please edit your post to add the Windows version at least.

Do the Fn keys work to control your USB keyboard AFTER you've done whatever you need to do in OpenRGB? I feel a valid solution may not be down the path you're currently pursuing. Could you describe a little more what the entire problem/symptoms/scenario are? Maybe we can find a valid solution that doesn't involve programmatically scripting the disconnect/reconnect thing.

If you close OpenRGB .  Do you regain control?

You might try a script using pnputil to disable and enable the keyboard (as would be done through Device Manager): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530182/enabling-disabling-a-device-in-windows-10-from-command-line, e.g., pnputil /disable-device "USB\VID_045E&PID_00DB\6&870CE29&0&1", replacing VID_045E&PID_00DB\6&870CE29&0&1 with device id. See Events tab of Device Manager properties for VID

Check if there are any firmware/driver updates for the keyboard - I think ROG distributes all theirs through Armoury Crate? I found similar behavior in the OpenRGB issue here - it's a long discussion, but maybe some of the troubleshooting steps might help you narrow down the issue: https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/issues/3151

@Ramhound No, I don't regain control if I close (even completely close with taskkill) OpenRGB

@music2myear I've written that "It seems that OpenRGB takes fully and exclusive control of the LEDs, so I'm forced to manually unplug and replug the keyboard to make them works again". If I input a color from OpenRGB then I can only change the keyboard color again from there and only there, nowhere else. Fn + arrow keys don't work anymore

How about Dynamic Lighting?

@Ramhound No, Windows doesn't recognize it as a Dynamic-Lighting-compatible device.

I've also installed Armoury Crate and AURA Creator to update the keyboard driver but nothing changed. In there there's a toggle to turn on/off the lights, but probably there's no way of toggling it via cmd

It sounds to me like power cycling the keyboard is the key thing here, rather than simply disabling the driver, the functions the OS exposes programmatically. If this is a serious enough problem, and you MUST use this OpenRGB utility, then you should probably look into a programmatically switchable USB hub or connector.

@music2myear I've already searched for it but I didn't find it. Online there's only a "smart" (iOT) usb connector from chinese brands which is Alexa compatible, even if I could make this automation to work, it's quite big and ugly to see. Also this is a non-urgent problem I'm just trying to solve, in order to not doing things manually every time I sit on my desk and turn on my monitor to use my PC again. I'm also changing my setup and so the keyboard, I own that one from ROG for more than three years now, it's old and not even hot-swappable.

@music2myear The ideal product would be a tiny USB-A female to male connector that can be programmed to interact with the PC and switched on/off. But I really don't think it could exist or at least being purchased online
